# Конвертирование и редактирование комментариев?

Tags: поддержка, модерация, ответы, комментарии

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, исходя из обсуждения "[Mark a comment as answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question)", что у пользователей, занимающихся модерацией больше не будет возможности возможности превращать ответы в комментарии и наоборот? Что делать в таком случае с ответами типа *"Спасибо, что помогли"*?
2. Что с редактированием комментариев? В обсуждении [Should we be allowed to edit comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments) упоминается, что модераторы могут редактировать комментарии. Имеются в виду модераторы, выбранные на Выборах модераторов или пользователи с привелегией [Инструменты Модератора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если правильный ответ в комментарии, то у вас несколько путей:

1. Сообщить автору комментария, что решение из комментария работает, и следует отправить его как полноценный ответ.
2. Самостоятельно скопировать комментарий в ответ. Правилом хорошего тона будет отметить ответ как "общий", чтобы не "воровать" репутацию.
3. Часто ответы в комментариях — сообщения о тривиальных исправлениях, например, опечатках. В таком случае вопросы следует закрывать с причиной "опечатка".

Конвертацию StackOverflow не поддерживает. Вообще, отношение к комментариям на СО пренебрежительное: они могут быть только однострочными, продолжительное обсуждение не рекомендуется, модераторы без зазрения совести вычищают комментарии. Идея в том, что, если есть важная информация, она должна быть в посте.

Пользователи с привилегией модератора (10К на СО, 2К на бетах) редактировать комментарии не могут. И вообще редактирование комментариев — это исключительное событие. Если что-то в комментарии не так, то его скорее удалят полностью. И это тоже могут делать только "ромбовые" модераторы.

Собственно, в описании привилегии чётко перечислено, какие права появляются. Если что-то не перечислено, то его нет. "Власть" очень ограниченная, и на пафосное звание "модератора" не тянет, на мой взгляд.

**P.S.** Описание привилегии почему-то устаревшее. Советую смотреть на версию на главном сайте. На самом деле у "общественных модераторов" отобрали право обработки флагов, оставив только возможность голосовать за удаление.

Comment: Как общий помечать не обязательно. Комментарий может быть ошибочным. И за решение превратить его в ответ нужно отвечать. Похожее обсуждение -- [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251597/4279)

Comment: @jfs Вы можете сослаться на конкретное место, где это мнение озвучено? Не знаю, что "ответственного" в получении репутации. Наполучать столько минусов в репутацию, чтобы они перевесили плюсы — почти всегда нереально (минусов должно быть в 5 раз больше плюсов). А голосовать за общий ответ всё равно можно, то есть индикатор правильности никуда не девается.

Comment: место -- большой опыт использования сайтами. Вы переоцениваете значение очков репутации -- это не единственный и не главный стимул. Общие ответы подразумевают коллективное редактирование -- с другой стороны в ответ с владельцем не следует вносить изменения, которые меняют его смысл, даже если ответ ошибочен (можно проголосовать, оставить комментарий, добавить собственный ответ).

Comment: @jfs Разумеется, репутация — не стимул для тех, у кого 100К+. Джон Скит тоже так говорит. :) Для меня репа вполне была стимулом до порядка 10К, но потом полезные привилегии кончились, и явные пороги для этого числа пропали. / С редактированием всего и вся всеми, вики-постами, использованием вики как наказания и прочим такая чехарда, и постоянно что-то меняется, что я слабо понимаю, какое официальное предназнчение вики-постов. Скажем, я не встречался со мнением, что, если пост "общий", то можно менять его смысл на противоположный.

Comment: @jfs К вопросу о стимулах. Вот график: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252691 :)

Comment: не вижу графика, только таблица ([она доступна в помощи](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). Репутация -- это просто функция времени, проведённого на сайте (у кого-то она растёт чуть быстрее, у кого-то медленнее). Полномочия модератора, такие как удаление/восстановление комментариев, интересны очень небольшому кругу (очень полезных) людей. Для большинства по-прежнему, очки репутации *"это не единственный и не главный стимул"*.

Comment: @jfs Я в уме представил график по `median_next_*`. А так да, таблица. В справке этих полей нет, посмотрите внимательней. :)

Comment: В справке нет, потому что это просто предложение. Будет ли оно реализовано, в какой форме -- ещё не известно.

Comment: @jfs Похоже, я криво выразился. Я не про предложение из ответа, я про табличку из него, в которой укзывается активность пользователей (написание и редактирование постов) в зависимости от репутации (точнее, про кусок текста между первой и второй горизонтальной линией). Она явно говорит, что активность затухает после получения 10К.

Comment: Понял. Моя вина -- я просто проигнорировал последнее два столбца с основными данными ([избирательное внимание](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ahg6qcgoay4)). Да таблица действительно о стимулах. Хотя сложно что-то о конкретных выводах сказать (как обычно, "есть ложь, наглая ложь и статистика").