# Как пометить отвеченным вопрос, на который автор ответил, но не отметил что вопрос решен?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов

Периодически я встречаю вопросы, на которые автор ответил или согласился с ответом в комментариях, но не отменил как "отвеченый" (завершенный).

[Например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/516717/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-core-data)

Такие вопросы подолгу висят в "Неотвеченные вопросы".
Как правильнее отметить решенным такой вопрос? Нажать "тревога"?

Comment: Спасибо, стало понятно

Answer (score 4):

**Никак.**

Здесь нет самоцели сделать все вопросы с пометкой "решено" (зелёная галочка у одного из ответов вопроса). Чем-то подобным грешат форумы на msdn, насколько я помню. Там модераторы отмечают ответы как "решение", если ТС не сделал это сам за определённое время.

При этом сам термин "закрытие  вопроса" означает на SO невозможность дать ответ. Вопросы закрываются по причинам "дубликат", "не по теме", "слишком общий" и т.д.

Comment: Тогда я наверное не совсем верно выразился. Не "закрыть", а отметить отвеченным. Я понимаю что нет такой цели, но когда я ищу информацию по какому то вопросу, вопросы без ответов часто пропускаю, а там в комментариях иногда бывает проверенный (или данный) автором ответ. Не очень удобно угадывать.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk если действительный ответ написан в комментарии, Вы имеете полное право перенести его в форму ответа. [Подробнее](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/27/176217).

Comment: Спасибо, это хороший вариант