# Почему комментируют, а не отвечают?

Tags: обсуждение

Почему многие участники дают полезные ответы как комментарии, а не как, ВНЕЗАПНО, ответы? Даже не трогаю то, что за ответ они получат больше "плюшек". Но ведь из-за того, что, к примеру, мне дали верный ответ в комментарии, я не могу отметить его как полезный и закрыть вопрос. Он (вопрос) формально остается открытым и будет отображаться в общем списке, тем самым смущая пользователей.

Comment: Причины могут самые разные. Основная - недостаток времени для написания полноценного ответа. Просто напишите полноценный ответ сами или подождите, когда это сделает кто-то другой.

Comment: ... ответил @vp_arth в комментарии... Хм.. Почему-то мне кажется, что так уже с Grundy было - а не дубликат ли?

Comment: и вот: [Конвертирование и редактирование комментариев?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/23/186999)

Comment: Связанные вопросы: [Нужно ли давать ответ отдельным сообщением, когда автору вопроса хватило комментария?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4670/213987) и [Что делать с вопросом, на который дали ответ в комментарии к вопросу?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5225/213987)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Написание правильного ответа это целый ритуал. Правила запрещают, например, [давать просто ссылку на ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) или не объяснять код, приведенный в ответе. Также следует не забывать, что ответ, оформленный неправильно, могут также заминусовать, а автор вопроса может, например, по незнанию, не отметить ответ как правильный. В результате время, потраченное на написание полноценного ответа может быть потрачено зря. Также бывает обидно потратить много времени на написание полноценного ответа и в конце узнать что тебя обошли (как сейчас, например).

Все это причины, по которым вместо ответа может быть такая отписка.

Обратите еще внимание на один замечательный факт. У меня на сайте два золотых знака — один из них — "Непризнанный гений" — выдается он за более 25% правильных ответов с нулевым рейтингом. Т.е. более четверти ответов, отмеченных правильными не получили никакого дополнительного рейтинга.

Если вас, как автора вопроса смущает, что вопрос висит неотвеченным, сделаете следующее: сами потратьте время и напишите ответ на свой вопрос. Если Вас смущает, что вы получите за него не причитающиеся вам баллы, отметьте его как общий и укажите в тексте автора правильного ответа.

Comment: Поправка: не нужно делать ответ общим. Написание ответа должно вознаграждаться даже если оно было сделано по "подсказке" в комментариях.

Answer (score 22):

Тому есть несколько причин:

1. Автор комментария не уверен, что его сообщение является ответом. Из-за неоднозначности проблемы в вопросе или, например, если он приводит просто ссылку.
2. Сообщение является скорее подсказкой, направлением для поиска ответа, а не собственно ответом.
3. Расписывать ответ просто лень, а вот подсказку оставить можно. В виде комментария.
4. Ответом могут быть несколько возможных вариантов (из-за неясности вопроса) и в комментарий идёт один из них в виде предположения.

Что с этим делать? Просить автора комментария написать это в ответ. Если он молчит/отказывается и вам не лень, то можно самостоятельно написать ответ на свой вопрос с указанием что подсказка в комментарии.

Comment: Только не нужно спрашивать автора комментария, это трата времени впустую. Если бы он мог написать ответ - он бы сразу писал ответ.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, не готов согласиться) Для п. 1 и 4 часто после подтверждения ТС о верности решения из комментария его таки в ответ пишут)

Comment: @PavelMayorov не правда, я иногда пишу мелочи в комменты, и если это и правда по итогу решает проблему автора, и меня просят написать ответом, то я даю более развернутый ответ.

Comment: @teran а вы сильно обидитесь если ответ кто-нибудь напишет за вас?

Comment: @PavelMayorov а с чего мне обижаться то вообще?

Answer (score 7):

Возможно, потому что

> *Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте,
>   решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям.*

Вопросы, порожденные опечаткой или какой-то другой нелепостью возникают довольно часто. Так как маловероятно, что кто-то с подобной ошибкой придет к этому вопросу из поисковика, на вопрос стоит повесить тревогу, а в комментарии указать автору вопроса на ошибку.

Зачем публиковать ответ, если по мнению комментирующего вопрос должен быть закрыт и удален.